# How to test a UDP server limit?

Tags: udp

A server listening on a UDP port, many clients can connect to it, there are many groups of clients connected to it. In a group one client is sending message and the server needs to route the message to the rest  in the group. Like this many groups could be running simultaneously. How can we test what is the maximum number of connections the server can handle without inducing a visible lag in the response time ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let me desrcibe your network topology again. There is a server and many clients, clients are divided into several groups. A client sends a message to the server, and then the server sends something to the other clients in that group.

If the topology is like what I describe above, is the connections limitation you want to reach about how many clients the server can send to at the same time? Or do you want to know how many clients can send to server at the same time?

The way to test these two different circumstances may be using multi-thread or go routine if you can write by go. But they need to set different judge to give out the limitation.

Comment: Both. I have seen the topology works fine with a server and few clients. It is necessary the data being transmitted from one clients to other almost in real time, i.e. not a significant lag. Now  in real scenario these groups will be under different network, each client will have a different ip, how to simulate a simulate a situation like that and test the server limits.

Comment: So you already have a correct way to send to the groups. Then I think there are two steps to do the test. First you can take some little tests like create many thread with ip like 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.xxx.xxx, and divide them to different groups, grdually increase the number of clients/groups.

Comment: The second step is using vmware or virtual box to simulate different networks. And increasing the number of clients/groups gradually.